# Error during build of cpp file in VSC: "Errors exist after running preLaunchTask 'C/C++:cpp.exe build active file"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, mingw-w64

I am unable to run my code and execute the build of the .exe file in the cpp language in Visual Studio Code.

I have downloaded and installed GCC, MinGW software, MinGW-w64 GCC, etc. according to the instructions [here](https://www.msys2.org/) and have successfully verified that gcc g++ and gdb are all installed (by checking 'gcc --version' etc in the commad prompt). My intent is to use this compiler to compile my code but it seems I cannot find the correct compiler under the options listed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M43mE.png) to simply 'build and debug the active file'.

I also (and perhaps consequentially) have run into a problem with launch.json not being able to build the executable file.

Can someone please help me with this? This is incredibly frustrating and I simply want to be able to run my code. I downloaded MinGW along with gcc is a good compiler for this very purpose.

Image of error message 1: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxqqt.png), to which I click 'debug anyway' and get the next error:
Image of error message 2: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t4Yq.jpg).

Image of launch.json with the configuration that I thought would be appropriate (I found this from another source online): [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkEcT.png).

Thank you!!

Comment: I'm not about to click through to a bunch of pictures that should be text in the question. It's also entirely reasonable to assume you wrote bad code. The best way to utilize MSYS2's mingw is to use the terminal they suggest in VS Code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with terminal.
Well, I'll let the person who actually wrote the code (not me) know that :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend deleting all the configurations under the `.vscode` directory, as they can be regenerated again. After deletion, follow the steps:

1. Go to your program file, and press <kbd>F5</kbd> to launch debug.

   [image: Debugging settings]
2. Select `g++.exe build and debug active file` or a convenient option.

   [image: g++.exe build and debug active file]
3. A `tasks.json` under the `.vscode` will be generated with the appropriate instructions and the program will be executed instantly.

   [image: Working debugger]

   For example, in my case, it was this:

   ```json
   {
       "tasks": [
           {
               "type": "cppbuild",
               "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
               "command": "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin\\g++.exe",
               "args": [ // ----- given by me in C/C++ extension settings
                   "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                   "-Wall",
                   "-O3",
                   "-pedantic",
                   "-g",
                   "${file}",
                   "-o",
                   "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
               ],
               "options": {
                   "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
               },
               "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
               "group": {
                   "kind": "build",
                   "isDefault": true
               },
               "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
           }
       ],
       "version": "2.0.0"
   }
   ```